# ionic cordova add platform ios error in onesignal-cordova-plugin

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, cocoapods, onesignal

I'm having this error when running: **$ ionic cordova add platform ios**.
can you help me?

thanks!

**Versions:**

"cordova-ios": "^5.1.1",

"@ionic-native/onesignal": "^5.19.1"

"onesignal-cordova-plugin": "^2.8.1"

**Error:**

```
Installing "onesignal-cordova-plugin" for ios
"framework" tag with type "podspec" is deprecated and will be removed. Please use the "podspec" tag.
Failed to install 'onesignal-cordova-plugin': undefined
(node:23148) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
CordovaError: Promise rejected with non-error: "/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:439:in `help!': \u001b[31m[!] You cannot run CocoaPods as root.\u001b[39m (CLAide::Help)\n" +
  '\n' +
  '\u001b[4mUsage:\u001b[24m\n' +
  '\n' +
  '    $ \u001b[32mpod\u001b[39m \u001b[32mCOMMAND\u001b[39m\n' +
  '\n' +
  '      CocoaPods, the Cocoa library package manager.\n' +
  '\n' +
  '\u001b[4mCommands:\u001b[24m\n' +
  '\n' +
  '    \u001b[32m+ cache\u001b[39m      Manipulate the CocoaPods cache\n' +
  '    \u001b[32m+ env\u001b[39m        Display pod environment\n' +
  '    \u001b[32m+ init\u001b[39m       Generate a Podfile for the current directory\n' +
  '    \u001b[32m+ install\u001b[39m    Install project dependencies according to versions from a\n' +
  '                 Podfile.lock\n' +
  '    \u001b[32m+ ipc\u001b[39m        Inter-process communication\n' +
  '    \u001b[32m+ lib\u001b[39m        Develop pods\n' +
  '    \u001b[32m+ list\u001b[39m       List pods\n' +
  '    \u001b[32m+ outdated\u001b[39m   Show outdated project dependencies\n' +
  '    \u001b[32m+ repo\u001b[39m       Manage spec-repositories\n' +
  '    \u001b[32m+ setup\u001b[39m      Setup the CocoaPods environment\n' +
  '    \u001b[32m+ spec\u001b[39m       Manage pod specs\n' +
  '    \u001b[32m+ update\u001b[39m     Update outdated project dependencies and create new Podfile.lock\n' +
  '\n' +
  '\u001b[4mOptions:\u001b[24m\n' +
  '\n' +
  '    \u001b[34m--silent\u001b[39m     Show nothing\n' +
  '    \u001b[34m--version\u001b[39m    Show the version of the tool\n' +
  '    \u001b[34m--verbose\u001b[39m    Show more debugging information\n' +
  '    \u001b[34m--no-ansi\u001b[39m    Show output without ANSI codes\n' +
  '    \u001b[34m--help\u001b[39m       Show help banner of specified command\n' +
  "\tfrom /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:47:in `run'\n" +
  "\tfrom /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'\n" +
  "\tfrom /usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `load'\n" +
  "\tfrom /usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'\n"
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova:29:15
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova platform add ios exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

**`ionic cordova platform add ios --buildflag="--allow-root"`**